# Is calling React Web App by Iframe a good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have a React Web App **build** (index.html) that is called using an Iframe.

Iframe is an expensive call and I tend not to use it.

But I was glad to find that it hides all React details from Chrome web tools.
I consider it as good security measure.

However, I lost the routing displayed as uri (I am using HashRouter).

Can anyone highlight more pros and cons for using or not using Iframe?
I wonder whether Iframe for React App is good or bad?

Note, similar question was asked - but not for Web Applications

Comment: It's not 'good security measure' by no means. Everything that happens on client side can be debugged, reverse-engineered and tampered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barring some other reason to do so, no, you would not want to do this.

1. The React devtools still work just fine, you just need to load the iFrame independently.
2. If exposing your compiled React app is a security concern you've done something wrong.
3. The contents of your iFrame are still available just like any other page.
4. An iFrame is not “an expensive call” — it's an HTML element that instructs a browser to render content from another resource. The overhead associated with an iFrame is higher than embedding content directly, but whether or not it's excessive or justified depends on the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I still wonder if there are use cases where Iframe might be a good idea.

Comment: @Mulli Yeah, when you need to expose content on a webpage that exists under a different content security policy. See: Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with DevTools. Frontend can't do harm to your website, especially if you build your React app in production. Also iframe takes time to load, so it is better not to use frames for React.